# TinyMCE editor prevents bubbling of scroll events

Tags: javascript, tinymce, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using TinyMCE inside a container that has custom scrollbar (by mCustomScrollbar) but when I try to scroll over an editor, the scrolling stucks.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it (try to scroll it using a mouse wheel): https://jsfiddle.net/moaLsfnv/

```
tinymce.init({ selector: ".mytextarea" });
$('#container1').mCustomScrollbar({ theme:"dark-3" });
```

Is there any way to make editors bubble all the scroll events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an editor thing, it's an iframe thing. Here's a replication case that doesn't load TinyMCE:

https://jsfiddle.net/1gw82qkb/

If you want to avoid editing content in an editor, try `inline: true` mode (although that means using divs instead of textareas):

https://jsfiddle.net/saw5hdmL/

That breaks in different ways, however, because tinymce depends on window scroll events to make the toolbar follow the editor as it moves. But it does show what I mean that scrolling works when you aren't using iframes.